# Django unit test not modifying database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-unittest

I am creating a unit test for a view `PersonRemoveView` that simply modifies a datetime field called `deletion_date` in a model called `Person`. This field is `None` until this view is executed, then it is set to `timezone.now()`

The problem is that the value of `deletion_date` is `None` after executing the view from the unit test.

This is the test:

```
def test_person_remove_view(self):
    person = models.Person.objects.get(pk=1)
    request = self.factory.post('/person/remove/{}'.format(person.id))
    response = PersonRemoveView.as_view()(request, pk=person.id)
    self.assertIsNotNone(person.deletion_date)
```

and this is the view:

```
class PersonRemoveView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Person
    success_url = reverse_lazy('control:person_list')

   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.object = self.get_object()
       self.object.deletion_date = timezone.now()
       self.object.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

I have been debugging and the `dispatch` method is executed as expected but the temporary test database does not change and the `assertIsNotNone` method fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Models instances are not shared so you have to reload your instance in the test to find out if the view correctly changed the underlying database record:

```
def test_person_remove_view(self):
    person = models.Person.objects.get(pk=1)
    request = self.factory.post('/person/remove/{}'.format(person.id))
    response = PersonRemoveView.as_view()(request, pk=person.id)
    # reloads our instance values from the database
    person.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertIsNotNone(person.deletion_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your test, you get the Person instance from the database, then you execute the view, that modifies the database, but not the object you retrieved before. You need to call `person.refresh_from_db()` ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db)) after you execute the view, to get most recent changes from database.